# Calculate log2 ratio

Tags: odds-ratio

I have to calculate log2 ratio for odds and don't know how to do it.

```
 Group A      Group B
 0.031571     0.0170071
```

There are occurrences of event in `GroupA` and `Group B` - I want to calculate how much `Group A` has this specific event compared to `Group B`, hence I need log2 for odds ratio.

I was thinking that such ratio should be calculated like this:

```
log2(GroupA/GroupB) = log2(0.031571/0.0170071) = 0.892463
```

However in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16165594/2481693) they calculate it like this:

```
(GroupA/GroupB)/log(2) = (0.031571/0.0170071)/log(2) = 2.67814
```

My question is - how to calculate log2 ratio; and what is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Remember that the log of a ratio is equal to the difference of the logs: $\operatorname{log}_{k}(a/b)=\operatorname{log}_{k}(a)-\operatorname{log}_{k}(b)$, where $k$ is the base ($k=2$ in your case). Maybe that helps you figuring out if this is what you want to calculate.

Comment: Apparently, in the link I gave they tried to calculate log of a ratio in `awk` and `awk` can't calculate `log2(A/B)` and one has to `log(A/B)/log(2)`.

Comment: I added a comment to that SO answer pointing out the mistake. I think it's just a typo, but because it resulted in hugely erroneous example output, I have also downvoted that answer pending a correction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The log odds ratio is the log of the odds ratio, not the odds ratio divided by a log. I don't know what problem the link you gave was trying to solve, but it wasn't this one. You take the log of the OR because the OR is bounded by 0 and infinity and is multiplicatively symmetric around 1; while the log(OR) is unbounded and additively symmetric around 0.